# How to declare table in function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to create a function do to certain processing on data to be returned to a SQL view.

I have designed the function as below, but am getting error saying

> Must declare the table variable
>   "@FINALRESULTS"

although I have defined it as table.

Can you please help me making this function executable.

Appreciate your help!!

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.names(@CUSTID varchar(20), @effdt varchar(20))
RETURNS @FinalResults1 (Name1 nvarchar(254), Name2 nvarchar(254))
AS
BEGIN   
  DECLARE TABLE @FinalResults (Name254 nvarchar(254), SRNO nvarchar(3))

  CREATE TABLE @FinalResults (Name254 nvarchar(254), SRNO nvarchar(3))

  INSERT INTO @FinalResults
     SELECT(C.NAME1),ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.SEQ_NBR) 
     FROM PS_ARB_CU_CLST_STN A , PS_ARB_CU_STATIONS C 
     WHERE A.EFF_STATUS = 'A' 
       AND A.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(B.EFFDT) 
                      FROM PS_ARB_CU_CLST_STN B 
                      WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID 
                        AND A.CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID 
                        AND B.EFFDT <= @effdt) 
       AND A.SETID = C.SETID 
       AND A.ARB_STATION_ID =C.CUST_ID 
       AND A.CUST_ID = @CUSTID
       AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(D.EFFDT) 
                      FROM PS_ARB_CU_STATIONS D 
                      WHERE C.CUST_ID = D.CUST_ID
                        AND D.SETID = C.SETID 
                        AND D.EFFDT <= @effdt)
 ORDER BY 
    A.SEQ_NBR

DECLARE @Name nvarchar(254), @FULLNAME1 nvarchar(128), @FREEZENAME1 nvarchar(10), @append NVARCHAR (254)
DECLARE @FULLNAME254 nvarchar(254), @FULLNAME2 nvarchar(128), @FREEZENAME2 nvarchar(10), @COUNT INT, @i INT

SET @Name = ''
SET @FREEZENAME1 = 'FALSE'
SET @FREEZENAME2 = 'FALSE'
SET @FULLNAME1 = ''
SET @FULLNAME2 = ''
SET @FULLNAME254 = ''
SET @COUNT = 0
SET @i  = 0

SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM @FinalResults 

WHILE @i < @COUNT
BEGIN
  IF  @FULLNAME1 = ''  
    IF(LEN((SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/')<= 40 AND @FREEZENAME1 = 'FALSE' )
       SET @FULLNAME1 = (SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i  + '/');
    ELSE
       SET @FREEZENAME1 = 'TRUE';
    END IF
  ELSE 
    IF (LEN(@FULLNAME1 +(SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') <=40 AND @FREEZENAME1 = 'FALSE' )
      SET @FULLNAME1 = (@FULLNAME1 +(SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') ;
    ELSE
      SET @FREEZENAME1 = 'TRUE';

    IF @FULLNAME2 = ''   
       IF (LEN((SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/')<= 40 AND @FREEZENAME2 = 'FALSE' ) 
          SET @FULLNAME2 = ((SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') ;
       ELSE
          SET @FREEZENAME2 = 'TRUE';
       END IF
    ELSE
       IF (LEN(@FULLNAME2 +(SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') <=40 AND @FREEZENAME2 = 'FALSE') 
    SET @FULLNAME2 = (@FULLNAME2 +(SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') ;
       ELSE
    SET    @FREEZENAME2 = 'TRUE';

       END-IF
       END-IF
       END-IF
       END-IF

IF @append = '' 
            @append = (SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i );
         Else
            @append = @append + '/'+ (SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i );
          END-IF

     END-IF
SET @i = @i +1
END
END-WHILE

  If (Len(@append) < 40) 
      @FULLNAME1 = RTrim(@FULLNAME2, '/');
   End-If;
   If ((Len(@append) > 40) And
         (Len(@append) < 80)) 

      @FULLNAME2 = RTrim(@FULLNAME2, '/');
   End-If;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #FinalResults1 VALUES ( @FULLNAME1, @FULLNAME2)
END
RETURN 

END 

GO 
 SELECT Name1 
 , Name2 
  FROM @FinalResults1
```

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE TABLE @FinalResults (Name254 nvarchar(254), SRNO nvarchar(3))


CREATE TABLE @FinalResults (Name254 nvarchar(254), SRNO nvarchar(3))
```

Should just be

```
DECLARE @FinalResults TABLE  (Name254 nvarchar(254), SRNO nvarchar(3))
```

Additionally the return type of the function should be

```
RETURNS @FinalResults1 TABLE (Name1 nvarchar(254), Name2 nvarchar(254))
```

There seem to be still more syntax errors (why are you using `END-IF`?) but that should answer the question asked and I have no intention of going through fixing them all.

Comment: Thanks Martin!! I am new to SQL not sure of syntax.. :( ..searching and trying to sort out each syntax one by one. Do appreciate yor help.

Comment: @Dhiraj Is this ported from another RDBMS? `END-IF` is not valid `TSQL`. You need to use `IF(<condition>) BEGIN <multiple statements block> END`

Comment: @Martin No it is refrencing same database. Can I use 'ELSE' in this as its giving exception saying incorrect syntax near ELSE?

Comment: @mARTIN Do you mean BEGIN and END for each if and else condition like   IF  @FULLNAME1 = ''  
 BEGIN  
          IF(LEN((SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/')<= 40 AND @FREEZENAME1 = 'FALSE' )
          BEGIN
    SET @FULLNAME1 = (SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i  + '/');
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
       SET @FREEZENAME1 = 'TRUE';
       END
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
         IF (LEN(@FULLNAME1 +(SELECT NAME254 FROM @FinalResults WHERE SRNO = @i )+ '/') <=40 AND @FREEZENAME1 = 'FALSE' )
         BEGIN
      <stmt>END

Comment: Yes. Like `IF (1=1) BEGIN PRINT 'YES' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END` It is not strictly necessary if the block only contains a single statement but doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Hi, I have been able to create function but only after excluding Rtrim part. When I do include Rtrim it looks for argument and gives exception. However I have passed the arguments in form of variable @FULLNAME2 & @FULLNAME1. Secondly, when I am trying to call the function by "select * from funcname ('parm1','parm2')" its keeps on executing it for long.. Am I caling it correctly ?